# Form to edit table selected from combobox

Tags: ms-access

I have several (many, 30+) tables of values ready for use in comboboxes on various forms. I want users to be able to add values to these tables in case they need an additional value while filling out a form, but I do not want to create 30+ identical forms (one for each table) to make edits. So, I have a form where I can select one of the tables from a combobox and then open another continuous form that will eventually be used to show and edit the values in the table I selected. What I can't figure out is how to link the continuous form text fields to the table I selected in the previous form. I need to be able to set the textBox control source to something like [Tables]![[Forms]![FormToSelectWhichTableToEdit]![Combo0]]![DropdownValues], but I have the wrong syntax or something.[image]

Comment: For one thing, that ControlSource is an expression and not a textbox bound to field which means user cannot input anything. Need VBA to explicitly set form RecordSource and textbox ControlSource to specific field name - without equal sign. Or use UNBOUND form and controls and VBA to execute updates/inserts to table. Are you familiar with combobox NotInList event?

Comment: June7 no I'm not familiar with NotInList? I am pretty good with VBA in Excel but in Access I haven't been able to figure out where to place code...

Comment: NotInList event is a means to allow users to add a new lookup record "on-the-fly" during data entry. The event can take user input and directly add to table or open a form for user to input new record. Common topic.

Comment: Tried it out. That still leaves me needing to create a unique form for every one of my 30+ different lookup fields. I am wanting a way to programmatically load data from the relevant table into a single form since every table has one field with the same name.

Comment: No, can incorporate generic form with code as already described. If every table has one field with same name, why 30+ tables and not one? Could edit question to provide sample data. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.